# How do I cast a DATEDIFF result to decimal?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, casting, triggers

I hope you can help me to find the answer for this, I´ll explain my problem.

I'm working with biometric marking device database in SQL Server 2005, actually I'm developing software for extra hours calculate, so I'm working on 2 different databases (mine and biometric device db).

I'm trying to calculate the difference in hours between 2 dates which would be the 2 marking records by employee in 1 day using `DATEDIFF`, I want to save it as decimal for example 1.5 hours, this way later I´ll be able to sum and get accurate data.

I'm trying to achieve this using a trigger and a stored procedure, the trigger execute every time 1 new marking record is inserted.

The only thing the trigger does is execute my stored procedure, at this point everything works the only problem I have the casting to decimal from `DATEDIFF` function.

Here is my trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_marcas_ins] 
ON [dbo].[Marcas]  
AFTER INSERT
AS
     DECLARE @codigo VARCHAR(10);
     DECLARE @fecha DATETIME;

     SELECT @codigo = i.Codigo 
     FROM inserted i;

     SELECT @fecha = i.Fecha 
     FROM inserted i;

BEGIN
    EXEC dbHorasExtra.dbo.calculohoras @fecha,@codigo;
END
```

Here is my stored procedure script code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calculohoras] 
    @fecha DATETIME, 
    @codigo VARCHAR(10) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fechainicial DATETIME;
    DECLARE @fechafinal DATETIME;
    DECLARE @horas DECIMAL(6,2);
    DECLARE @createdat VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @updatedat VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @codigoemp VARCHAR(255);

    BEGIN
        SET @codigoemp = (SELECT id 
                          FROM nempleados 
                          WHERE codempleado = @codigo)
    END

    SELECT fecha 
    FROM Reloj_3216R.[dbo].Marcas 
    WHERE Codigo = @codigo 
      AND DATEPART(YEAR, fecha) = DATEPART(YEAR, @fecha) 
      AND DATEPART(MONTH, fecha) = DATEPART(MONTH, @fecha) 
      AND DATEPART(DAY, fecha) = DATEPART(DAY, @fecha);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT >= 1
    BEGIN
        SET @fechainicial = (SELECT MIN(fecha) 
                             FROM Reloj_3216R.[dbo].Marcas 
                             WHERE Codigo = @codigo 
                               AND DATEPART(YEAR, fecha) = DATEPART(YEAR, @fecha) 
                               AND DATEPART(MONTH, fecha) = DATEPART(MONTH, @fecha) 
                               AND DATEPART(DAY, fecha) = DATEPART(DAY, @fecha)
    )

    SET @fechafinal = (SELECT MAX(fecha) 
                       FROM Reloj_3216R.[dbo].Marcas 
                       WHERE Codigo = @codigo 
                               AND DATEPART(YEAR, fecha) = DATEPART(YEAR, @fecha) 
                               AND DATEPART(MONTH, fecha) = DATEPART(MONTH, @fecha) 
                               AND DATEPART(DAY, fecha) = DATEPART(DAY, @fecha)
        )
    END
    ELSE
        RETURN

    SELECT * 
    FROM horas 
    WHERE codempleado = @codigo 
      AND DATEPART(YEAR, fecha) = DATEPART(YEAR, @fecha) 
      AND DATEPART(MONTH, fecha) = DATEPART(MONTH, @fecha) 
      AND DATEPART(DAY, fecha) = DATEPART(DAY, @fecha)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        RETURN
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @updatedat = GETDATE();
        SET @createdat = GETDATE();
        SET @horas = 
        (
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@fechafinal, @fechainicial)/60
        )
        --INSERT INTO horas (codempleado,fecha,horas,created_at,updated_at) VALUES(@codigoemp,@fechafinal,@horas,@createdat,@updatedat);
    END
END
```

Sorry if I didnt ask correctly, I´ll provide any info you ask! Ty for your help!

**UPDATE:
@horas decimal(2,2) changed to @horas decimal(6,2) that solved the problem! thank you so much!**

Comment: For starters, there is a problem when inserted have more than one record

Comment: You've provided a picure of the error, but not in English. Stack overflow is an English website, and as the error is an image, the volunteers here can't paste that into a translator. Can you please translate the error so that others can understand it. Thank you.

Comment: try `declare @horas decimal(6,2);` You use `declare @horas decimal(2,2);` this only storage values from 0.00 to 0.99

Comment: `DATEPART(YEAR,fecha)=DATEPART(YEAR,@fecha) and DATEPART(MONTH,fecha) = DATEPART(MONTH,@fecha) and DATEPART(DAY,fecha) = DATEPART(DAY,@fecha);` Why not `CONVERT(date, fecha) = CONVERT(date, @Fecha)`? The latter is SARGable, and far easier to understand.

Comment: DATEDIFF returns an int, not a decimal. It counts the number of thresholds crossed between two dates. If you want some kind of running calculation of the difference between dates you need a different approach entirely. Decide how much leeway you have. Maybe a minute variance is ok? Then get the sum of the datediff calculations and do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: And your trigger logic has a MAJOR flaw!!! It assumes there will only ever be a single row in the inserted virtual table. Triggers need to be set based, not using scalar variables.

Comment: "I already tried using but doesnt work:"   doesn't work how?    be very very specific.

Comment: Ask a new question. Add table structure, data sample, and ask for help in calculating period of working time.

Comment: Also, how are you trying to update the row? it looks like your using the "edit top 200 rows" utility of SSMS. Using an actual `UPDATE` statement might yield a more informative error.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I´ll translate the error, and declare @horas correctly

Comment: Hey Horaciux, your answer solved my problem! Thank you so much!, im trying to mark it as the correct one but cant find how to do it!

Comment: Larnu, I tried to use convert but it trows me an error that the function doesnt exist which probably is related to my SQL Server version (2005)

Comment: Hi @AlexQuezada, you need to include @ before user name to get a notification.

Comment: Oh! ok! thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the comment as an answer as OP suggested

try `declare @horas decimal(6,2);` You use `declare @horas decimal(2,2);` this only storage values from 0.00 to 0.99 – Horaciux 2 hours ago

Comment: Ty! it worked like a charm! Sorry I cant mark the answer as correct cause I dont have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

As you already have learnt, the trigger must not expect just one new record. To execute the stored procedure for every new record, you will have to use a cursor like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_marcas_ins] 
ON [dbo].[Marcas]  
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @codigo VARCHAR(10);
     DECLARE @fecha DATETIME;

     DECLARE insertedcur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
       SELECT Codigo, Fecha FROM inserted;

    OPEN insertedcur;

    FETCH NEXT FROM insertedcur INTO @codigo, @fecha;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      EXEC dbHorasExtra.dbo.calculohoras @fecha,@codigo;
      FETCH NEXT FROM insertedcur INTO @codigo, @fecha;
    END

    CLOSE insertedcur;
    DEALLOCATE insertedcur;
END
```

Your stored procedure can be simplified a little, but even when changing the `@horas` variable to `decimal(6,2)`, the result will always be an integer, because `DATEDIFF` returns an integer and `60` is also an integer. To fix this, divide by `60.0` instead. You procedure could look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calculohoras] 
    @fecha DATETIME, 
    @codigo VARCHAR(10) 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    DECLARE @fechainicial DATETIME;
    DECLARE @fechafinal DATETIME;
    DECLARE @horas DECIMAL(6,2);
    DECLARE @createdat VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @updatedat VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @codigoemp VARCHAR(255);

    SET @codigoemp = (SELECT id 
                        FROM nempleados 
                        WHERE codempleado = @codigo);

    SELECT @fechainicial = MIN(fecha), @fechafinal = MAX(fecha)
    FROM Reloj_3216R.[dbo].Marcas 
    WHERE Codigo = @codigo
      AND CAST(fecha AS date) = CAST(@fecha AS date);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      RETURN;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM horas 
               WHERE codempleado = @codigo 
                 AND CAST(fecha AS date) = CAST(@fecha AS date))
      RETURN
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @updatedat = GETDATE();
        SET @createdat = GETDATE();
        SET @horas = 
        (
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@fechafinal, @fechainicial)/60.0
        )
        --INSERT INTO horas (codempleado,fecha,horas,created_at,updated_at) VALUES(@codigoemp,@fechafinal,@horas,@createdat,@updatedat);
    END
END
```

Comment: Wow, thats awesome! I mean the cursors, honestly I knew that there was a problem with my trigger thinking about execute it and read every single row in the table, I wasnt sure about how to ask for this but helped me a lot!! Thank you so much!